# Excel ¿Cómo hacer una serie de celdas automaticamente de 3 en 3?

Tags: excel, formulas

Tengo una tabla de excel, pero quiero arrastrar el valor de la celda sin que me cambie las filas o las columnas. El problema es que solo quiero que cambie la fila cada 3 celdas, ejemplo.

- =A1
- =A1
- =A1
- =A2
- =A2
- =A2

y así, el problema es que no lo hace y si lo anclo solo me devuelve A1 en todo. Ayuda gracias

Answer (score 0):

He simulado unos valores de A1 a A6, y luego en la columna C he hecho lo que quieres, cada 3 filas cambia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi fórmula en C1 y arrastrando es la siguiente:

```
=INDIRECTO("A" &REDONDEAR.MAS(FILA()/3;0))
```

Aquí usamos varias funciones útiles de Excel:

1. La parte `FILA()/3` devuelve el número de fila actual y lo divide entre 3 (3 porque tú lo quieres cada 3 filas, si lo quisieras cada 5, cambia el 3 por un 5)
2. `REDONDEAR.MAS(FILA()/3;0)` Aquí redondeamos la división anterior al número entero **superior**, es decir, 1,2 o 3 dividido entre 3 siempre dará 1, 4,5,6 dividido entre 3 siempre dará 2, etc.
3. `"A" &REDONDEAR.MAS(FILA()/3;0)` Aquí simplemente concatenamos la letra A con el número entero obtenido en el paso anterior. Esto irá cambiando cada 3 filas, obteniendo A1,A2,A3.. y así sucesivamente
4. Finalmente usamos la función INDIRECTO, muy útil. Esta función devuelve el valor que haya en la celda que tú escribas como argumento. Si, por ejemplo, escribes en B1 `=INDIRECTO("E30")` devolverá el valor que haya en la celda E30. Entonces, como nosotros en el paso anterior estamos obteniendo A1,A2,A3, etc. lo usamos como argumento de esta función. `INDIRECTO("A" &REDONDEAR.MAS(FILA()/3;0))` Y es la fórmula completa.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.